# Difference between adjective and gerund - he loves playing

Tags: differences, nouns, adjectives, gerunds

He loves playing

In this statement - is playing a noun(gerund) here or an adjective?

According to me it should be adjective as it telling additional information about the subject ("he" here).

Comment: No, it is the object of _loves_: the sentence is exactly parallel to "He loves ice-cream".

Comment: It's ambiguous between a noun and a verb, but certainly not an adjective.

Answer (score 3):

> *He loves playing*

is strictly speaking ambiguous, though verb preferred ("He loves to play").

Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in "occasional playing".

In the verbal interpretation, "playing" is complement of "loves"; in the noun interpretation it is direct object.

Comment: Right.  To illustrate the ambiguity, one can compare "He loves playing loudly" where it must be a verb, with "He loves loud playing." where it must be a noun.